# Create 7-Zip Archive with Files from Textfile - Powershell

Tags: powershell, archive, 7zip

I'm coding a small Powershell application at work for our supporters to Archive Files. But now im stuck because of the 7zip Option.

The Users can select a Day and Directory and the Code selects all Files which were modified before that Day.

Now i want to store all these Files in a Zip Archive but i don't get it :(

```
    $path = Read-Host "please select path : "

    Set-Alias sz "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe"


    $bis = Read-Host "please select date (dd.mm.yyyy): "
    $bisdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($bis,'dd.MM.yyyy',$null)

    $files = Get-ChildItem $path | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $bisdate}  |     ForEach-Object { $_.FullName} > C:\Test\list.txt
```

I found several samples for 7zip operations but can't find a solution for this Situation. Is there any option like in Bash? Something like that?

```
    zip archive -@ < out.txt
```

Comment: BTW. sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create archive with this code ifyou has `7z.exe` and `7z.dll` in specified directory:

```
foreach ($filePath in [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("c:\Test\list.txt"))
{
    $archParams += "`"" + $filePath + "`" "
}
$archParams = "a `"C:\Test\list.zip`" " + $archParams

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -Wait -ArgumentList $archParams
```

The escaping of qoutes are necessary because of `space`-symbol in paths to files

Comment: This creates a Zip-File with list.txt in it. I need to archive the Files which are listet in the list.txt File.

Comment: I changed code to add to archive all files wich full pathes are in `list.txt`

Comment: This Works! Thank you soso much!! :D unfortunately this just creates a Zip once... if i want to create another one it doesen't work. After a restart it works again one time.. do i have to kill a process or something? Thx in Advance :) EDIT: Close Powershell ISE and open up again works too

Comment: In `Powershell ISE` you need to clean up `$acrhParams` manualy because of `Powershell ISE` do not re-create variables before re-running the script. I use `PowerGUI` and I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "7za". It is a 7zip-console-application. You find it using google.
Place it in a common path, which is in you path-variables.

Here is an example:

```
7za a -tzip "C:temp\myzip.zip" "C:\temp\Client\*.*"
```

Comment: This Archives all the Files from Directory C:\temp\Client\. Thats not what i need. I have to build an Archive which just contains the Files listet in my Textfile...